# Gradle: keep access to extra properties when split build.gradle on several parts

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have the simple `gradle.build` file

```
ext {
    port = 10001
}

task expand(type: Copy) {
    // Substitute property tokens in files
    expand(module_name: project.name
            ,     port: port
    )
}
```

It works like a charm without any problems.

Then I want to refactor my build script and split `build.gradle` on `build.gradle`:

```
apply from: 'rpm.gradle'

ext {
    port = 10001
}
```

and `rpm.gradle`:

```
task expand(type: Copy) {
    expand(module_name: project.name
            ,     port: port
    )
}
```

Task `gradle expand` fails with

> Error:Could not get unknown property 'port' for task ':expand' of type
>   org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.

How to resolve it by modifiing only the `build.gradle` with next constraints:

- using of `gradle.properties` is not allowed (Of course it is strange condition. It appeared due usage of `gradle.properties` by other plugin in auto-mode on CI-server)
- `rpm.gradle` cannot contain actual value of `port` property, becouse `rpm.gradle` will be read-only and shared from single place across several members of the team

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You try to use port before you defined it.
Swap that and it should work like

```
ext {
    port = 10001
}

apply from: 'rpm.gradle'
```